# How to remove Chromium browser without removing Lubuntu Desktop

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu, chromium, browser, synaptic

I am trying to remove the Chromium browser through Synaptic, but it tries to remove  Lubuntu desktop. How can I remove it keeping Lubuntu desktop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chromium is specified as a dependency of the `lubuntu-desktop` package, so uninstalling it will cause the `lubuntu-desktop` package to be uninstalled.  However, `lubuntu-desktop` is only a metapackage; removing it will not actually uninstall the Lubuntu desktop environment.

The only problem you will have is that when you upgrade to the next version of Lubuntu, the `lubuntu-desktop` package will be reinstalled and with it Chromium.